# why documentum webtop is shiped with java windows jre

Tags: documentum, webtop

I found 2 big files in documentum webtop

```
 webtop\wdk\contentXfer\win-jre1.6.0_16.zip
 webtop\wdk\contentXfer\win-jre1.5.0_06.zip
```

Why webtop is shipped with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all your users have java on their PCs then you can delete the JREs packaged with webtop. I have done this before. Also I stripped out other files not used. For example:

- the help files (not used as client did their own help)
- Delete Sources and Web Workflow manager
- Remove Themes
- Remove UCF Jars and JRE

  Make sure to check the runtime java version setting in: "wdk/contentXfer/ucf.installer.config.xml"

  Your PC clients must have at least this version of java installed. This is from Webtop 6.7

Answer (score 2):

Webtop version 6.0 and above uses Java Applet for file operations
such as check-in, check-out, import etc.

EMC named this technology as UCF. So to execute the Java Applet of this UCF 
technology Webtop shipped with Windows JRE.

Comment: You mean the JRE is needed for clients lacking one. Webtop can make them download and install it and get the applets working. The JRE is not directly used by Webtop.

Comment: Right! JRE get used to execute UCF related applet on client browser. So one need to manually download compatible JRE version and install it on each client for successful UCF operations.

Comment: Actually these applets (UCF) are in all Webtop versions. Part of the core WDK framework